# why is the transformation matrices behaving differently

Tags: opengl, matrix, glm-math

I get different results when scaling objects.

The  objects have four different glm::vec3 values

```
 1) Position , Rotation , Scaling , Center Point
```

This is the  Transformation Matrix of the object

```
   TransformationMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMatrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

The rotation and scaling Matrix looks like this.

```
glm::vec3 pivotVector(pivotx, pivoty, pivotz);
glm::mat4 TransPivot = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), pivotVector);
glm::mat4 TransPivotInverse = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), -pivotVector);
glm::mat4 TransformationScale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(scax, scay, scaz));
return   TransPivot * TransformationScale * TransPivotInverse;
```

In the first case.

[image]

I move the rectangle object to 200 units in x.

Than i scale the group which is at position x = 0.0

so the final matrix for the rectangle object is

```
 finalMatrix = rectangleTransformationMatrix * groupTransformationMatrix
```

The result i what i expected.The rectangle scales and moves towards the center of the screen.

[image]

Now if i do the same thing with three containers.

Here i move the group container to 200 and scale the Top container which is at position 0.0

```
   finalMatrix = rectangleTransformationMatrix * groupTransformationMatrix * TopTransformationMatrix
```

the rectangle scales at its own position as if the center point of the screen has also moved 200 units.

[image]

If i add -200 units to the pivot point x of the top container than i get the result what i expected.

where rectangle moves towards the center of the screen and scales.

If someone can please explain me why i need to add -200 units to the center point of the Top container.Whereas in the first case i did not need to add any value to the pivot point of the scaling container.

when both the operations are identical in nature.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

First case

```
Rectangle - > position( x = 200 , y = 0, z = 0) , scaling( 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) , Rotation( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )
glm::mat4 PositionMatrix = glm::position( // fill the values);
glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = glm::scaling( // fill the values);
glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::rotate( // fill the values);
RectangleMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

the matrix for group

```
 froup - > position( x = 0.0 , y = 0, z = 0) , scaling( 0.5 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) , Rotation( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )
groupMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

final result
 finalMatrix = RectangleMatrix * groupMatrix

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Second case

```
Rectangle - > position( x = 0 , y = 0, z = 0) , scaling( 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) , Rotation( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )
glm::mat4 PositionMatrix = glm::position( // fill the values);
glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = glm::scaling( // fill the values);
glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::rotate( // fill the values);
RectangleMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

the matrix for group

```
 group - > position( x = 200.0 , y = 0, z = 0) , scaling( 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) , Rotation( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )
groupMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

the matrix for Top

```
 Top - > position( x = 0.0 , y = 0, z = 0) , scaling( 0.5 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) , Rotation( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )
TopMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

final result
 finalMatrix = RectangleMatrix * groupMatrix *  TopMatrix

Comment: If `groupTransformationMatrix` contains scaling, then the translation of `TopTransformationMatrix` is scaled, too

Comment: @Rabbid76 can i  please request you to please explain this in bit more detail , why did it not happen in the first case.

Comment: @Rabbid76  the groupTransformationMatrix = positionMatrix() * rotationMatrix() * scalingMatrix() , but scaling value is 1.0 for all the axes.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I do not understand the content of `groupTransformationMatrix ` and `TopTransformationMatrix`. In first case there is no `TopTransformationMatrix` at all. Note, If `M7 = M1 * M2 * M3` and `M8 = M4 * M5 * M6`, then `M7 * M8 = M1 * M2 * M3 * M4 * M5 * M6`. Write the transformations in a row to see the difference.

Comment: @Rabiib76 thank you , i will update my question with the contents of both the matrices.

Comment: @Rabid76 i have updated my question with the contents of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix operations are not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). `scale * translate` is not the same as `translate * scale`

If you have a translation of 200 and and a scale of 0.2, then

```
translate(200) * scale(0.2)
```

gives object scaled by 0.2 and translated by 200. But

```
scale(0.2) * translate(200)
```

gives object scaled by 0.2 and translated by 40 (0.2*200).

If you have 2 matrices:

```cpp
groupMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
TopMatrix = PositionMatrix() * RotationMtrix() * ScalingMatrix();
```

Then `groupMatrix * TopMatrix` is the same as

```cpp
groupPositionMatrix * groupRotationMtrix * groupScalingMatrix * topPositionMatrix * topRotationMtrix * topScalingMatrix
```

The result is different if the scale is encoded in `groupScalingMatrix` or `topScalingMatrix` respectively the translation is encoded in `groupPositionMatrix` or `topPositionMatrix`.

Comment: Thank you very much i understand now why i was having different results .if i would want to scale the Rectangle object with respect to center of the screen ,what should i be doing ?

Comment: Currently i am adding inverse of the group Container position to the Pivot of the Top container  , is this the correct approach ?